# Jasny Bootstrap File Upload Image Preview Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I have recently noticed that the file upload image preview on my site is not working. It previously did work. The current state is that the Select Image prompt works, asks you to select a file and, if you submit the form, it actually adds the image into the DB. However, the stats prompting the image preview and interactive buttons (change/remove) do not work.

What makes this problem specifically difficult is that I cannot see any specific javascript errors associated with the file and the plugin file itself loads from the S3 server.

The image previews can be found: https://www.rigsandwagons.com/listings/add/

Comment: It seems to break as soon as you type in something in any other field.